# Regexp: replace multiple groups with unknown groups number

Tags: regex, shell, perl

Let's say I want to replace

```
function (foo, bar, some, other) {
```

With

```
function (foo:any, bar:any, some:any, other:any) {
```

*Important:* **I don't know how many arguments function may have**.

it's gonna be something like `/function \((\S+),?\) \{/g` probably but with a various number of capture groups, I guess...

Is it a way to replace all matches with **Perl-styled RegEx**

P.S. I didn't found rexex-based solution, but I need exactly regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use single regex replacement using a `\G` based regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'function (foo, bar, some, other) {';
$s =~ s/(?:\G(?!\A),?|function\s*\()\s*\K(\w+)/$1:any/g;
print $s;
```

See an [online Perl demo](https://ideone.com/vuK2k5)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A),?|function\s*\()`  - either the end of the previous successful match and an optional `,` (matched with `\G(?!\A),?`) or (`|`) `function` substring followed with 0+ whitespaces and then a literal `(` (matched with `function\s*\(`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the whole text matched so far from the match buffer
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars.

Comment: Great! Many thanks. So the regexp as is would be `(?:\G(?!\A),?|function\s*\()\s*\K(\w+)`. Works like a charm. I'll accept this answer after few mins

Comment: is it possible to check if it closes with `{`character? Sorry, but it's can be important for me. (I've tried to add something like `(?:\)\s\{)` at the very end of the expression, but it's totally wrong ))

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov: Yes, sure, sorry, that evaded my attention. Just add the lookahead at the start: `function\s*\(` must be replaced with `function\s*\((?=[^)]*\)\s*{)` or maybe even like `function\s*\((?=.*?\)\s*{)`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this perhaps?

It uses a substitution nested within another substitution. The outer one finds the parameter list, while the inner one adds `:any` after each parameter in the list

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'function (foo, bar, some, other) {';

$s =~ s{\bfunction\s*\(\K([^()]+)}{
    my $params = $1;
    $params =~ s/[^\s,]+\K/:any/gr;
}eg;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
function (foo:any, bar:any, some:any, other:any) {
```